# Can't install Ubuntu due to a problem with the media

Tags: system-installation

I Just tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 by using USB device. I used universal usb installer to make my pen drive boot-able. But I am getting this error always.[image]

I already have 12.04, but I want to replace it by 12.10.

Is there any other way to install Ubuntu 12.10 ??

Update:
I tried with burning DVD, but getting same error. I don't have free space so I am unable to upgrade also, is there way to install without using Ubiquity?

Comment: Try upgrading to ubuntu 12.10 using these instructions:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-10

Answer (score 1):

First, check out if your ISO matches the [MD5 Hash for 12.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). If so, use the Startup Disk Creator on 12.04 once again to put the ISO on the USB drive. You can also burn a DVD, or use the [Software Updater](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10), but if you know how to use the USB that is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

What did you selected in the beginning of the installer, when it asks *how* Ubuntu should be installed? *(Install Ubuntu 12.10 next to 12.04 or Replace Ubuntu 12.04 with Ubuntu 12.10 or delete Ubuntu 12.04 and install Ubuntu 12.10 or Manually configure settings)*

If you haven't yet selected the last one, you could try this. Then you can select a formatted partition on which you want to install Ubuntu 12.10.

If you've already tried this without success, try to use the default "usb-creator" instead for setting up your bootable USB-Device.