# Upgrade using terminal commands

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

i have heard many ways to upgrade to ubuntu 12.10 using terminal (I am currently in 12.04 LTS). What is the best way to upgrade through terminal? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look this answer [How to safely upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-10) everything is using terminal.