# How do I Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to 12.10?

Tags: dist-upgrade

I tried updating and it doesn't show the upgrade.  Can I install from the terminal?  I'm new to this, but I haven't messed my computer up so far.  What steps do I take?

Comment: Have you checked the following [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-10)? Looks like it might be a similar solution.

Comment: Please research before you ask questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to safely upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-10)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to System Settings -> Software Sources & Updates tab -> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version -> in drop down list select "For any new version" and Close.
2. Open up the Software Updater and check for updates. After that you will see the 12.10 version of ubuntu on software updates. Click upgrade.