# Should I pick William Donovan or Chomsky for my server and why does the software make presumptions

Tags: mirrors

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 by upgrading since my download copy was not booting the OS. It failed to reboot  as soon as I restarted 13.04 after installing it. This occurred several times so I can't chalk it up to fate as I see on Googles others have had this problem.

Thus I used my copy of 12.04 that is a Canonical provided copy to start the installation and just upgraded the OS after a minimal install with 12.04 and 12.10 using 32 bit copies. I normally use the 64 bit variety of Ubuntu but wanted to go ahead and test out 13.04 to keep up with what improvements the fantastic and dedicated community of developers and engineers have in store for the faithful.  I upgraded my system using the recommended script at debianhelp.wordpress.com and after using this script, I am getting a "failed to download repository information" error when I use the Anarchist logo upgrade button on this version of Ubuntu.

I noticed my updates seemed a little slow  so I used the "what is the best server for my location" test in the software and updates window to tell me the best location for updates for my computer. Since I live in Central Pennsylvania, I was surprised when I got a response that I should use a mirror in Singapore. Not only that, the server name serves to remind me that perhaps I had perhaps ventured into Wild Bill Donovan territory. Here's the URL of where I was redirected. http://linux.ntuoss.org/ubuntu

Now I don't mind helping Wild Bill Donovan, but can anyone explain why this anomaly occurred?  I'm switching over to the Chomsky mirror at MIT until I can understand why it is necessary to send me out of the country for upgrades to my garden variety computer.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to have used a third-party script for upgrading, the most likely source of problems is such script.

It is best to follow the procedures indicated [answering this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/203301/58950), which make use of Ubuntu's repositories and regular distribution upgrading procedures.