# Where is the update-manager?

Tags: updates

I can't seem to upgrade to the latest version ubuntu. It asked me once, but I was doing something else at the time. Now that I ant to do it I can't find it. I can find software updater, but that just seems to update programs that are on the computer.

Comment: Did you try `sudo do-release-upgrade` ? What version are you on, btw?

Answer (score 2):

The update manager has the upgrade button you are looking for.

start the update manager with typing `update-manager` in a terminal. The upgrade button will be shown there.

Or you can search for it in dash by typing update manager.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Gear on the top-right corner> System Settings...>Software&Updates
there go to the Updates Tab and then check that "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version is set to: For any version.
then execute the Software updater and it should tell you (if not hit refresh)
Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type update-manager at the prompt or do the same in Terminal.

If this does not show the update open a Terminal window and type in

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*The `sudo apt-get upgrade` command updates any installed software requiring an update before you proceed*

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

*This searches for and upgrades your system*

[How to safely upgrade from an older Ubuntu version to a newer one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-an-older-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer) Is the best and safest way.

***Edited with corrections suggested below***

Comment: `sudo apt-get install` needs a package name after....

Comment: OK, but it tells you if there is anything that needs updating. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`

Comment: the `sudo apt-get upgrade` would upgrade any available software. the `sudo apt-get install` is just random, makes no sense...

Comment: You are so correct! I must have had a bad 5 minutes when I wrote the answer and didn't really check it properly. My apologies :(