# How can I update Ubuntu if I "missed my chance"?

Tags: 13.04, updates, update-manager

When the new 13.04 became available I had no internet. Still, it appeared on my Update Manager (not relevant, but HOW?). When I got internet back and opened the Update Manager the button to update to 13.04 was nowhere to be found.

How can I install the 13.04 now?

Comment: Which version are you using *now*?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/203301/62483

Answer (score 0):

If the update manager doesn't work you can use a live usb/cd of Ubuntu 13.04.

You can simply make one using [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

After creating the live usb/cd boot it and start the installation process.
You'll be prompted if you want to upgrade, install side by side or do a clean install.
Click upgrade.
[image: instal promt]

If you do not have your home folder on a separate partition you may want to back it up before doing this!