# Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade failure

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

I'm trying to upgrade ubuntu my ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, but there is always this error:

*Error during update 
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 
W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.canonical.com/dists/[distro]/partner/source/Sources 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80] 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead.*

---

It's not the internet connection
 problem. My internet works fine.... i have good connection.

Can someone help me with this problem?
Thanx

Comment: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/[distro]/partner/source/Sources is not a valid source url. Did you follow the steps in [how-to-safely-upgrade-from-an-older-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer-one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-an-older-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer-one)? You need to delete or deactivate old ppa entrys in sources.list

Comment: Please Open a terminal (Alt+Ctrl+T) and add the outcome of "cat /etc/apt/sources.list" as an edit to your question. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

you have to try with changing to some other server , in deed from best server option.

Open software sources application from dash, from there you can change your software server.

Comment: I tried to do that, but nothing has changed. The same error anyway