# how do i upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04? I have tried nothing yet,however this is trying my patients,
I have been here for over an hour trying to ask a simple question and this  is my LAST ATTEMPT!!!

Comment: @JorgeCastro 12.10 isn't an "old unsupported release".

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-an-older-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer-one

Answer (score -1):

run "sudo do-release-upgrade". 
I do not recommend upgrading to 13.04 because of the many bugs it has compared to 12.10 or 12.04.